# How to go to next page on Github API

Tags: android, api, web-services, github, pagination

With [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination). I want to use `rel="next"` instead of incrementing the parameter `page` manually

This's my `Service.java` `Interface` *(using [retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/))*:

```
@GET("user/repos")
Call<Repos> getRepos(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, 
@Query("page") int pageIndex);
```

How can I do it? **Android** - *using Java*

Answer (score 0):

By principle, HTTP `RESTful` APIs are stateless.

This means the `Github` API doesn't know what your current page is, and what your next page is.

Therefore, you must pass the `page` and `per_page` parameter.

`rel="next"` in the Link header indicates that the resource request is for the next page, but it can't and shouldn't be used to get the next page results without passing the `page` parameter.

> In the simplest case, a link relation type identifies the semantics
> of a link.  For example, a link with the relation type "copyright"
> indicates that the resource identified by the target IRI is a
> statement of the copyright terms applying to the current context IRI.

> Link relation types can also be used to indicate that the target
> resource has particular attributes, or exhibits particular
> behaviours; for example, a "service" link implies that the identified
> resource is part of a defined protocol (in this case, a service
> description).

From [RFC-5988 Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988)